# Spring Rest dummy API implementation based on the user ID

Tags: spring-boot

We have a restful API having only basic filters with no spring security features like role,principal etc.,. Lets say there is an API end point /User/{ID}/BankAccounts

We would want to have a dummy user ID for testing purposes where the data would be mocked for an ID "123" and the actual API implementation for the rest of the users.

API structure is a collection of rest controllers, (have about 15) calling DB/WS.

We do not wish to make change on each controller but to do it at a centralized point.

Comment: There are plenty of ways of achieving it, adding a filter in the endpoint you want, and if statement, having this mock user data in the db, anyway. Could you elaborate more, give piece of code or something to help, thanks.

Comment: Dear Brother, Thanks for the swift response. I have updated the question, please review.

Comment: If you really want to mock this user, and you have clear separation of the services, you could have a service with "mock" activeprofile where using ID 123 returns the user mocked, or it calls the repository to retrive from database. If you can have the "mock" data on the database level, you can see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql